# How to count the total no. of asp.net checkboxes, checkboxes checked, no. of checkboxes remain unchecked in webform using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to count the total no. of asp.net checkboxes, checkboxes checked, no. of checkboxes remain unchecked in  webform using vb.net ?

I m using Visual studio 2008 with vb as a language ..

I my webform i have 10 checkboxes...

i wanna count total no. of checkboxes in webform in textboxes1
total no. of checkboxes checked in webform in textbox2
total no. of checkboxes remain unchecked in webform in textbox3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim intTotalCheckBoxes as Integer = 0
Dim intCheckBoxesChecked as Integer = 0
Dim intCheckBoxesUnChecked as Integer = 0

For Each chkbox as Checkbox in Page.Controls

If chkbox.Checked Then

   intCheckBoxesChecked += 1

Else

   intCheckBoxesUnChecked += 1

End If

intTotalCheckBoxes += 1

Next
```

If you have controls on your page that contain checkboxes and need to know how to recursively include those too, please add a comment and I'll edit the code.  Otherwise, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample C# code, you can easily develop VB code from it.

```
private int mTotal;
private int mChecked;

private void EnumerateCheckBoxes(Control control)
{
   if (control is CheckBox)
   {
     mTotal++;
     mChecked += ((CheckBox)control).Checked ? 1 : 0;
   }
   else if (control.HasControls())
   {
     foreach(var c in control.Controls) 
     {
       EnumerateCheckBoxes(c);
     }
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   mTotal = 0;
   mChecked = 0;
   EnumerateCheckBoxes(this.Form);
   textbox1.Text = mTotal.ToString();
   textbox2.Text = mChecked.ToString();
   textbox3.Text = (mTotal - mChecked).ToString();
}
```

Few things to consider:

1. This code will count radio buttons as well as because it gets inherited from CheckBox. If that is to be avoided then replace `if (control is CheckBox)` with `if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))`
2. If you wish to consider checkboxes from CheckBoxList then you have to write another condition to see if control is CheckBoxList and then within condition, enumerate items withing checkboxlist. Items count to be added to total count while selected items to be added to checked count.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I tried my hand at an actual VB answer and got waylaid by the language.  I also got distracted trying to select all CheckBox controls using LINQ. :-)